# R median and ecdf() function giving different results - Why?

Tags: r

I have a vector vec with 80 values, if I apply the median(vec) function I get a value. However what I would like to do is the reverse, given a number estimate the percentile it belongs. I've found the ecdf() function, however I´m getting different results. This a simplified example

```
> vec = c(100,150,150,150,150,150,200)
> median(vec)
# This gives the expected result
[1] 150

# However if I go the other way around, meaning I pass the value and try to return the percentile I get:
rev_med <- ecdf(vec)
rev_med(150)
[1] 0.8571429
```

!!!

The behavior I'm expecting is passing 150 and get 50% as this is the median of the vector

What's going wrong here?

Comment: there are six repeated 150 out of seven samples given a P(X<=150) = 6/7

Answer (score 2):

`ecdf` is giving the empirical CDF, which is a function `F` for which `F(x) = P[X <= x]` where `X` is the random variable producing the input vector `vec`.

It's an estimator; `median` is a different estimator.

But you can see that `ecdf` gives a reasonable answer:

```
mean(vec <= 150)
# [1] 0.8571429
```

Nevertheless, we can use the `ecdf` object to produce 150 as the median:

```
quantile(ecdf(vec), .5)
# 50% 
# 150
```

See `?ecdf`; this isn't a complete answer but hopefully it's illuminating anyway.

Comment: quantile(ecdf(vec), .5)  Indeed returns 150. But what I'm looking for is passing 150 and getting something closer to 50%.